# Unable to add Flurry Analytics to my iOS project

Tags: ios, flurry

I want to try Flurry analytics, but not any of the ad or video stuff. This is the most recent version, 4.0.1, which I just grabbed from their website.

I get this after adding the directory to my project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification", referenced from:
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer init] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification", referenced from:
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer init] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer playVideo:view:ad:] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer playVideo:view:ad:] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer playVideo:view:ad:] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer moviePreloadDidFinish:] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer playVideo:view:ad:] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer moviePreloadDidFinish:] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
  -[FlurryVideoPlayer stopMovie] in libFlurryAds.a(FlurryVideoPlayer.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - the Flurry API has changed so that rather than signaling `FlurryAnalytics`, you simply signal `Flurry`. This was documented in the comments of the `.h` file but scarcely otherwise.

I also had to remove the `FlurryAds` directory from the downloaded API (4.0.1) because I don't have its dependencies installed.

Answer (score 2):

In Flurry SDK v4.x for iOS, it is possible to integrate only the Analytics functionality. Please refer to the following files: Flurry/Flurry.h, Flurry/libFlurry.a and Analytics-README.pdf in the SDK folder. There are additional folders for use with Flurry Ads which are required only if would like to show Flurry ads inside your app.

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to remove from you're project all the flurry libraries (eg: libFlurryAds.a) and just left the libFlurryAnalitics.a

Comment: That file is not present in the archive provided - where do I find it? The only `*.a` files I only see are `libFlurry.a` and `libFlurryAds.a`.

Comment: Then you download the wrong SDK, Login into flurry -> go to your flurry application -> Click on the Home tab -> At your right there is a box called Manage Applications -> Download SDK -> Choose your Application.  You will find then `libFlurryAnalitics.a`

Comment: I have tried a bunch of times, I am sure this file is not in the SDK being provided. Any other ideas?

Comment: DELETE the flurry ads folder. I' guess I'm not using it and it was breaking stuff. Also don't forget to import Security.framework and SystemConfiguration.framework